# Stripe Elements Icon Padding Issue

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Elements on my site but running into some issues with the icon styling.
I've done some searching and found this [link](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/494) but they have closed the ticket saying the issue was fixed.

As you can see on my screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/q5LRMHm) the icon is flush to the edge and I'd like some padding to the left.

I've tried adding padding via my JS like so but it doesn't change anything.

```
var style = {
    base: {
        iconColor: "#fff",
        padding: "5px 10px 5px 20px",
        backgroundColor: "#a91537",
        color: "#fff",
        fontWeight: "400",
        fontFamily: "Montserrat, sans-serif",
        fontSize: "18px",
        lineHeight: "80px",
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        showIcon: false,
        textIndent: "10px",
        ":-webkit-autofill": {
            color: "#fff",
        },
        "::placeholder": {
            color: "#fff",
        },
    },
    invalid: {
        color: "#fa775a",
        iconColor: "#fa775a",
    },
};
```

I've even tried adding it via CSS but because it's pulled in via an iframe my styling does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be changing the style of the container you mount the Element to, not the Element itself. For example, if you were mounting your card element to `#card-element` you could add some basic styling like this:

```
<style>
  #card-element {
    padding: 12px;
  }
</style>

<div id="card-element"></div>
```

You can read more about this here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/the_element_container?type=card